# How to get plain xml from file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I search for a method to get plain xml(with tags ect.) from a file and save it so the localStorage.

I found a few opportunities, but every one of them returns the xml without tags. I prefer jQuery to do this...

I tried `$.get`, `$("").load()` and AJAX but I don't get it. I just want to save the whole xml as string into the localStorage and read it out later (and work with it).

Does anyone have a idea?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://example.com',
   dataType: 'text',
   success: function (data) {
      localStorage.setItem('xml-content', data);
   }
});
```

This will provide you the XML document as plain text and save it to the `localStorage`.

Here is a full solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<pre id="output">
</pre>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function setXML() {
        $.ajax({
           url: 'test.xml',
           dataType: 'text',
           success: function (data) {
              localStorage.setItem('xml-content', data);
              getXML();
           }
        });
    }
    function getXML() {
        var xml = localStorage.getItem('xml-content');
        $('#output').text(xml);
    }
    setXML();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to append the string from the localStorage to an div like $("#output").append(localStorage.getItem("store")); but this return the xml without tags. Then I tried to parse the string with $.parseXML but it return the exception "invalid XML".

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake on my side. But r.data return undefined.

Comment: I fixed it, it's just `data`

Comment: I tried to append the string from the localStorage to a div. "var xml = localStorage.getItem("xml-content")" returns the xml without tags. I tried to parse the xml with $.parseXML( xml ) but got the exception "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null". You know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your XML is valid? Also are you sure you use `dataType` : `text`.

Comment: See my update, for running it you need only `test.xml` file in the directory where's the HTML.